# (Swift) How to change Label text outside of cell (where the event occurs)?

Tags: swift, uitableview, events

I am unable to find a solution for this on my own, please help.

I have a table view with -/+ buttons inside that increase or decrease a value.

In the footer cell of the table is a label for the "total sum", the added value of all the cell values. When the value inside of a cell is decreased or increased, I want the footer cell text to change accordingly.

Any pointers how I go about that? I have tried to write a global function, but then I can't access the label anymore... tried it as a class method (static), but I can't seem to get it to work.

Can I somehow hook up the action that occurs in the UITableViewCell to trigger an action in the UITableView?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In the `UITableViewDelegate` associated to your table view, you should call the `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths: [NSIndexPath], withRowAnimation animation: UITableViewRowAnimation)` method to update your the row you wish to update.

Than it your `UITableViewDataSource` provide the footer cell with the good new value.

Comment: How do I call a method in the UITableViewDataSource from a button in a UITableViewCell?

Comment: If you defined your table view cell interface in interface builder, you should be able to make an IBAction from your button to your view controller, and from there (but it depends on your code) you will probably have access to your UITableViewDataSource object.